# Actions are not reflected in the interface

Tags: bug, android-app

Certain actions (notably upvotes) do not appear in the interface without exiting and reentering a question.

Upvoting comments consistently changes the color of the background, edits often won't appear until reentrance.

Upvoting answers is inconsistent, and when it does highlight the up arrow, the highlight is lost if after scrolling away and then returning.

The actions appear to be successful.  For example, subsequent upvotes trigger an error message indicating the answer has already been upvoted.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-G900V

  - OS Version: 5.0 (G900VVRU2BPB1)